# Open Record Specific LWC Subtab

Tags: lightning-web-components, workspaceapi

I am trying to get a `Lightning Web Component` to open a new subtab containing another `Lightning Web Component`. Our team has already established a hidden utility bar component which listens for post messages and passes them on to the `Workspace API`. I have my LWC posting a page reference to that component structured as follows:

```
wokrspaceAPI.openSubtab({
    "pageReference": {
        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__myComponent"
        },
        "state": {
            "c__recordId": "500..."
        }
    },
    "focus": true,
    "parentTabId": "ctab0"
})
```

However, while this call does open a new subtab, I just get a tab title of **`Page Not Found`** and no content renders. What is wrong with this structure?

For completeness, our metadata:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="myComponent">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: May be this is a naïve question to ask as I am learning LWC myself, but what you see from the console on the `Page Not Found` tab? Did you try to log any of the properties/values from the underlying LWC? Adding more details as such would help understand the issue better.

Comment: That's where I got the payload from in the first place. That's the very last step I have that returns anything. I pass that payload to the `Workspace API`, it opens a subtab, but something seems incorrect/corrupted about the `PageReference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this type of navigation is only supported for URL addressable Aura components. The documentation states as much in a few locations (cited below), though it is easy to miss (or at least I did).

It is worth noting that for me, this approach did not seem to pass through attributes from `state` neither with nor without the `c__` prefix. I may open a separate question to figure that out.

---

> ## [Using Page References to Open Console Workspace Tabs and Subtabs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_open_pagereference.htm)
>
> Use `openTab()` and `openSubtab()` with a `lightning:isUrlAddressible` component to open custom Aura components in Lightning console apps.

---

> ## [PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type)
>
> ### Lightning Component Type
>
> A Lightning component. To make an addressable Lightning web component, embed it in an Aura component that implements the `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface.

---

## Working Example

**NavProxy**

```
workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
    focus: true,
    parentTabId: "...",
    pageReference: {
        type: "standard__component",
        attributes: {
          componentName: "c__MyAuraUrlAddressable"
        },
        state: {
          uid: "1",
          myParam: param
        }
    }
});
```

**MyAuraUrlAddressable.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <aura:attribute name="myParam" type="Id" description="Id of the record" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <c:myComponent param="{!v.myParam}"></c:myComponent>
</aura:component>
```

**MyAuraUrlAddressableController.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component) {
        const pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
        component.set("v.myParam", pageReference.state.myParam);
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if we may open the LWC component in a same way?

Comment: Yes you just have to embed it in Aura (or at least you did).